# The content of a library MC when exported as SWF is empty

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, loader, children

I need to be able to iterate through the children of a movieclip when I generate a swf file using Flash pro.

The process I was doing before works works ok, but only if I publish the swf. It means, I place different objects in the stage (movieclips, textFields, buttons, etc) and as long as I type an instance name, I can retrieve that object by code, and do stuff later.

However, when I export a library movieclip to swf (right click on the movieclip in the library, export SWF...), and a new swf is generated, I don't have access to the children inside it.

If you need, I can provide some code, but its quite simple. I just use a loader and then I check the event.currentTarget.content, and inside content there are all the children I need.

Comment: What's wrong with the way you were doing it before?

Comment: That it doesn't work for movieclips exported as swf inside a library. There seems to be a need to have them in the stage.

Comment: That's caused by the garbage collector, if you're not "using" the library entries, they just get thrown away when you publish the swf. Exporting them for runtime sharing may prevent this.